# Mysql order on 2 columns

Tags: mysql, date, sql-order-by

I have a table 'activities' with two dates : begin_date and end_date.
I don't know how get a list of activities order by begin_date and end_date.

i.e : if I have 2 activities like that:

> name => 'activity1', begin_date => 1:00AM, end_date => 3:00AM
>
> name => 'activity2', begin_date => 2:00AM, end_date => 4:00AM

And I like to get:

> activity1, 1:00AM, (begin_date)
>
> activity2, 2:00AM, (begin_date)
>
> activity1, 3:00AM, (end_date)
>
> activity2, 4:00AM, (end_date)

Is it possible ? How can I do that in pure SQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.name, t.CombinedDate
    FROM (SELECT name, begin_date AS CombinedDate
              FROM YourTable
          UNION ALL
          SELECT name, end_date AS CombinedDate
              FROM YourTable) t
    ORDER BY t.CombinedDate
```